# How to compile gradle project to a jar file I can use in my Android application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, maven, gradle

I have an Android application that I've written in Eclipse. I like working with eclipse better than Android Studio.

I found a nice control on Github that I would like to use in my project https://github.com/pedant/sweet-alert-dialog

And it depends on the following project:
https://github.com/pnikosis/materialish-progress

I tried compiling with gradle but with no luck. What I need is a JAR file that I can use in my eclipse project. So I first tried to compile the sweet-alert-dialog project and I found out that I need to first somehow include the materialish-progress.

How can I compile those projects into a JAR file that I can drop in my eclipse project and use?

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse use apklib and gradle aar for packaging libraries. Aar is the recommended format to use by google but if you need to generate apklib from gradle you can add this code in your build.gradle

```
task apklib(type: Zip) {
    appendix = extension = 'apklib'

    from 'AndroidManifest.xml'
    into('res') {
        from 'res'
    }
    into('src') {
        from 'src'
    }
}
```

Then you could use this task by calling gradle apklib. You may have to adapt this snippet for your project.

[source](https://plus.google.com/+ChristopherBroadfoot/posts/7uyipf8DTau)

Comment: Will that compile to jar? forgot to mention, while my Android project is eclipse the gradle I compile from terminal

Comment: No. You will have an .apklib file you could import in your eclipse project as any library. No matter if you're using command line or android studio.

Answer (score 0):

Try to download *.aar files from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/cn.pedant.sweetalert/library/1.3 and http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.pnikosis/materialish-progress/1.0, extract class jars from them (they are just archives) and put to your libs folder. May be some resources will need to be copied from archives, too.. But I haven't managed it yet.